# Frequency not reflecting in time series object R despite specifying it using as.ts

Tags: r

I have a dataframe test_data. I convert it to time series.

```
test_data
         Date Quantity Discount Segment Ship_Mode
1  2018-02-01      345     5000      20        20
2  2018-03-01      500      300      50        20
3  2018-04-01      400      400      40        30
4  2018-05-01      200      400     100        20

test_data<-as.ts(test_data, frequency=12)
```

Now when I do below, I get the frequency of my data as 1 despite specifying it above as 12. What am I doing wrong?

```
frequency(test_data)
[1] 1
```

Comment: Use `test_data <- ts(test_data, frequency=12)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `as.ts` does not have `frequency` parameter, you should be using `ts` for that.

```
test_data<-ts(test_data, frequency=12)
frequency(test_data)
#[1] 12
```

Comment: Hi there is a problem . On doing `test_data<-ts(test_data, frequency=12)
`, I am getting date column as a separate column. Is it possible to take the date column as timestamp and get the pther columns'

Comment: On doing `test_data<-ts(test_data, frequency=12)
`, I am getting something like `Date Quantity Discount Segment Ship_Mode
Jan 1 17563      345     5000      20        20
Feb 1 17591      500      300      50        20
Mar 1 17622      400      400      40        30
Apr 1 17652      200      400     100        20`

Comment: Basically date column has been added as a separate column.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor Please don't change your question after it has been answered. This was not your original question. It invalidates current answers and confuses future readers. If you have additional question please ask as a new question. Thank you.

Comment: done.. pls answer this new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201812/timestamp-not-reflecting-well-on-changing-to-ts-object-in-r)