# Timestamp not reflecting well on changing to ts object in R

Tags: r

Original dataset

```
test_data
         Date Quantity Discount Segment Ship_Mode
1  2018-02-01      345     5000      20        20
2  2018-03-01      500      300      50        20
3  2018-04-01      400      400      40        30
4  2018-05-01      200      400     100        20
```

Trying to convert to timestamp, I get below output:

```
test_data1<-ts(test_data, frequency=12)
       Date Quantity Discount Segment Ship_Mode
Jan 1 17563      345     5000      20        20
Feb 1 17591      500      300      50        20
Mar 1 17622      400      400      40        30
Apr 1 17652      200      400     100        20
```

I want to understand how to get rid of the date column in the `test_data1`. Also my time stamps are not correct now. I wanted first date to be 1 Feb 2018 rather than Jan for e.g.

Comment: Is `ts(test_data, frequency=12, start = c(2018, 2))` what you want?

Comment: yes its solved using this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Daily time series with ts.. how to specify start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604432/daily-time-series-with-ts-how-to-specify-start-and-end)